# Attribute behaviour in python class using property decorator

Tags: python, oop, properties, decorator

I'm confused with how attribute variables are behaving in my class when using the property decorator.

See this example:

```
class Example:
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x

  @property
  def x(self):
    return self.__x

  @x.setter
  def x(self, x):
    self.__x = x
```

This works fine, but how? The variable inside the setter property (`self.__x`) has not been "defined" in the constructor, so how can it be assigned a value?

Other stuff also works, for example, take the same class defined above and add a new member function to it:

```
  def set_val_x(self):
    self.__x = 8765
```

Again, using this function actually works, similar to the property.setter (but it's not using the property decorator).

Comment: There's no requirement in Python that an attribute of an object has to be initialized in the constructor.

Comment: Python lets you create arbitrary attributes as needed (unless you're using e.g. `__slots__`).

Comment: A property is a *class* attribute that has special behavior when invoked via an instance. The class attribute `Example.x` is well defined by the time `Example.__init__` ever runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `__init__`, the line

```
self.x = x
```

is no longer short for

```
setattr(self, 'x', x)
```

because the class attribute `Example.x` exists. You are no longer creating an instance attribute `x`, but calling

```
type(self).X.__set__(self, 'x', x)
```

which will set the instance attribute `__x`.

Instance attributes can be created, modified, or deleted at any time. The `__init__` method is just a convenient, single place to create them because it is called for you automatically every time you create an instance.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you don’t have to define variables in the constructor. You can assign them whenever you want.

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
my_foo = Foo(3)
my_foo.other_thing = 6
```

is perfectly legal, for example.

Comment:  Thanks! I get it now.